# Automating Azure Logic App job creation and deployments

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am new to cloud and Azure, so I do not know how logical my thoughts seem. Please tell me if there are better approaches to solve the issue.

There is a SharePoint list of jobs with their corresponding Cron expressions. The jobs all execute same tasks but with different parameters and schedules.

What already is done is a logic app that is scheduled to run every 5 minutes to scan the list and run the jobs which match the current timestamp but I do not find it really logical.
I was thinking of something like having a script which creates separate jobs for each list item (like dynamic DAG creation in Airflow based on a template); however, I cannot find any resources to learn how to do it.

Can I create separate logic apps by using JSON representations of tasks for each item in SharePoint list with their corresponding parameters and deploying them on Azure using a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Below is something that you can follow to achieve your requirement, I have created the same flow as yours over logic apps expect for the part where I have added Azure function which creates separate jobs for each list item through HTTP trigger. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

I'm using the below sample code in my Function.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    body = req.params.get('name')

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{body}")
```

However, you can write your custom code inside it.

***IN SHAREPOINT FILE***

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]